# RShiny renders two images on top of each other

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am having the following problem.
I would like to render two plots beneath each other but apparently,
both of these always overlap.
The first picture should reamin it size.

My code:

```
plotOutput("Video", width = 1000, height = 1000),
div(style = "display:inline-block",
        plotOutput("farmplot"),
        tableOutput("summary_farm")),
    
div(style = "display:inline-block",
        plotOutput("wildplot"),
        tableOutput("summary_wild"))
```

'''

Thanks a lot! [the way it currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1Aqg.png)

Comment: elcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `fluidPage()` layout for your UI, you can use `fluidRow()` to separate elements vertically and `column()` to separate the horizontally. See more information on this in the Shiny Application layout guide: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(12,
      plotOutput("Video", width = 1000, height = 1000)
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(6,
        plotOutput("farmplot"),
        tableOutput("summary_farm")
    ), 
    column(6,
        plotOutput("wildplot"),
        tableOutput("summary_wild")
    )
  )
)
```